# Callback response from ControllerB to ControllerA

Tags: objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks

I need to make the SDK for one of my project, What I need to do is make a search class which return the response from the web API,

I'm looking for something like this.

```
SearchController * sc = [[SearchController alloc] initWithSearchText:@"google"];
```

This method is called every time, when I change the `textField` text, and the response I get should be in block.

Any help and reference would be appreciated.

Comment: you need only callback fuinction or whole function with your functionality? please describe more

Comment: i need the hole functionality,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SearchController.h

```
typedef void (^SearchHandler)(id results,NSError *error);

@interface SearchController : NSObject
{
    SearchHandler searchBlock;
}
-(void)searchWithText:(NSString *)strText Results:(SearchHandler)searchResult;
```

SearchController.m

```
-(void)searchWithText:(NSString *)strText Results:(SearchHandler)searchResult
{
    searchBlock = [searchResult copy];

    //call api for text search
}

-(void)getResponseOfApi
{
    //code where get api response
    searchBlock(apiResonse,apiError);
}
```

call SearchController api with block

```
SearchController * sc = [[SearchController alloc] init];
    [sc searchWithText:@"google" Results:^(id results, NSError *error) {
        //block with api response
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make one block method in your `SearchController` and get response of type you want.

```
-(void)executeSearchRequestWithHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHandler {
     //Do your api calling and than handle completionHandler
     completionHandler(YES);
     //You can set completionHandler type that you want like NSArray,NSString,NSDictionary etc
}
```

Now call this method like this.

```
[sc executeSearchRequestWithHandler:^(BOOL result) {
    if (result) {

    }
}];
```

**Note:** Here I have created block with `BOOL` parameter, you can set parameter type you want from response like `NSArray`,`NSDictionary`,`NSString` etc.